# How to perform a check on multiple sub-trees

Tags: json, bash, jq

What I'm trying to do currently, is, within each environment, compare mainAccount and secondAccount values.

If they do match, then I will trigger some downstream code to check the file version. If they do not, then I will pass. That is not really relevant, however I am struggling to compare the values across each environment. Since each .json file will have different amounts of environments.

Meaning, in testing environment, I want to check if mainAccount = secondAccount, and same in production environment.

I'm running into issues parsing this JSON with jq:

**json1**

```
{
    "file_version": 1.0,
    "config": [
        {
            "environment": "testing",
            "main": [
                {
                    "mainAccount": "123"
                }
            ],
            "second": [
                {
                    "secondAccount": "456"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "environment": "production",
            "main": [
                {
                    "mainAccount": "789"
                }
            ],
            "second": [
                {
                    "secondAccount": "789"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's another sample .json file for comparsion:

**json2**

```
    {
    "file_version": 1.3,
    "config": [
        {
            "environment": "testing",
            "main": [
                {
                    "mainAccount": "123"
                }
            ],
            "second": [
                {
                    "secondAccount": "456"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "environment": "production",
            "main": [
                {
                    "mainAccount": "789"
                }
            ],
            "second": [
                {
                    "secondAccount": "789"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "environment": "pre-production",
            "main": [
                {
                    "mainAccount": "456"
                }
            ],
            "second": [
                {
                    "secondAccount": "789"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "environment": "staging",
            "main": [
                {
                    "mainAccount": "234"
                }
            ],
            "second": [
                {
                    "secondAccount": "456"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If I run this command:

```
jq -r '.config[] | select(.main != null) | .main[].mainAccount
```

My output is:

```
123
789
```

If i store this output in a variable, it'll be `123 789` so comparing this to the "secondAccount" value is troublesome.

I think what I'm looking for is iteration here, however, I'm not sure how to implement this. I wanted to take a pythonic approach to check the length of the `config` array, create a for loop in that length range, then collect the value based on an index like

```
.config[0] | select(.main != null) | .main[].mainAccount
.config[1] | select(.main != null) | .main[].mainAccount
```

etc. The issue however, is that when I read in the `.config[]` value as a variable, bash doesn't interpret it like that. The length will be the length of characters, not, the amount of objects in the array.

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**
Nothing. I simply want to, for each .json file above, compare the mainAccount and secondAccount values with eachother, within each environment.

In **json1**, I want to compare mainAccount == secondAccount in environment: testing. Then mainAccount == secondAccount in environment: production.

Then move onto json 2 and compare mainAccount == secondAccount in environment: testing. Then environment production, pre-production, staging, so on and so forth.

Comment: >" I hope I was clear."
Since two answers are commented with "thats not what I want to compute" I think it's save to say: No.

Comment: I have made some edits to be a bit more clear. If the values match, is not really relevant, as long as I am able to match them.

Comment: When you say "If they do match", do you mean "if they match in ALL environments in the file being examined", or "if they match in the environment of interest as specified for example on the command line"?   Or something else?  Please try to clarify this and other aspects of the question.

Comment: If they match in the environment of interest. If they match env = testing, then in env = production

Answer (score 1):

Since all information is within this one JSON file it is better to do the processing in `jq` as much as possible and to keep the shell out.

Given your input you can try this `jq`:

```
jq '
    .config[]
    | {
        environment,
        condition: (.main[0].mainAccount == .second[0].secondAccount)
    }' input.json
```

The result is:

```json
{
  "environment": "testing",
  "condition": false
}
{
  "environment": "production",
  "condition": true
}
```

Some questions though:

- Why are the values of `first` and `second` arrays objects and not object?
- Is it really intended to match the first one of both?
- Can there be more items in the arrays?

Also: If you want to process the results in a shell, I propose this expression because the output can be used (`source` or `eval`) in a shell:

```
jq -r '
    .config[]
    | "\(.environment)=\(.main[0].mainAccount == .second[0].secondAccount)"' input.json
```

The output is:

```
testing=false
production=true
```

Comment: 1. Could you clarify a bit more what you mean here?

Comment: 2. Yes, it is, for my use case

Comment: 3. Yes, there can be. 

BTW, this answer is a bit closer to what I'm trying to do, but still doesn't solve it. Because you have to hard code the index for `.main[0].mainAccount == .second[0].secondAccount`

Comment: I am dealing with a problem where there are multiple .json files similar to those above. I am iterating through each .json file, and then having to compare, depending on how many environments in each .json whether the mainAccount and secondAccount values match. Across all environments. So unfortunately this hardcoding solution appears to only match the values in one environment, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: All three questions address the same place in your given example. Please provide a real example where the indices do NOT match.

Comment: And the expected output of course.

Comment: Sorry for my confusion. It really DOESN'T matter if indices match or do not match. My main goal is to be able to compare the values of mainAccount and secondAccount across each environment, for each .json file. So, there is really no expected output.

Comment: I have to be as blunt as possible, `Why are the values of first and second arrays objects and not object`? What does this mean. I don't understand what you mean. Why are they objects and not object? Please, like I'm a 5th grader, haha.

Comment: **Made some edits.

Comment: "Object" means `{ ... }` where `...` means zero or more `"key": value` pairs. "Array" means `[ ... ]` where `...` are zero or more values. `first` (which is wrong, I meant `main`) is currently formulated as `"main": [ { ... } ]` and not simply as `"main" : { ... }`. So far (i.e. without reading your edits of the Q) it is unclear which the additional `[]` is for.

Comment: Regarding your response to "2." and "3.": In "2." you write, that it is OK to compare the first values of `main` and `second`. But in 3. you complain, that exactly these indices are hard coded. This is a plain contradiction.

Comment: 1. Simply put, this is the formatting of the .json I am working with. I can't explain why they are objects nested in arrays, I didn't construct the files. My task is simply to parse them.

Comment: 2. I am sorry if this is causing any irritation. I really appreciate you taking the time to even provide help, so I apologize for any impression I gave off.

Comment: 2a. The reason the hardcoding is not what I'm looking for, is, then, how do I compare the `main` and `second` values for the subsequent environment? I believe I am looking for some sort of iterative process here. I'm not sure how to be more clear. I'm simply looking to iterate through each environment and compare main and second values within each environment, within each .json. I have found this is not that simple to do utilizing jq.

Comment: I think your confusion is about what the part is that does the iteration over the environments. Actually that is the `.config[] | ` part. After that the `jq` code only sees data from one environment and nothing else. So the two places where `[0]` is used are also constrained to the same environment -- they do **not** span multiple environments. These two places of `[0]` are necessary because your JSON says `"main": [ {` and not simply `"main": {` (and similar for `second` of course).

Comment: I see.. so now I'm wondering if there's a way to iterate through each `.config[]` element? like, if there's potential for 5 distinct environments, maybe I could construct a loop like  `for i in {1..5}` and I insert `i` as the index for config through each loop? get the main and second accounts for that environment, compare them, then move onto the next?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the comparison within `jq`, return the boolean result as its exit status using the `-e` option, and react upon that in `bash`, e.g. using an `if` statement.

```sh
if jq -e '
  .config | map(select(.main != null) | .main[].mainAccount) | .[0] == .[1]
' file.json >/dev/null
then echo "equal"
else echo "not equal"
fi
```

```
not equal
```

Comment: I have tried this out, and unfortunately it doesn't address what I'm trying to do. But it's a step in the right direction.

I want to compare the `mainAccount` value to the `secondAccount` value. Not `mainAccount` to `mainAccount`, across environments.

And I'll be working with .json files above that have more than just two environments. So `.[0] == .[1]` is adequate for a json file where config has two environments, but if there's more, I think I need a different solution.

Comment: @NicholasRinaldi Sure, you can perform any comparisons with a filter similar to the above, and aggregate it to one boolean output as shown. To help you with formulating the right filter (e.g. using `transpose` to align the arrays), more use cases and your desired outcomes are needed. In your sample, add more items to each of the arrays, maybe even differently many (or state that they are always the same size), and clarify how these different cases should be treated.

Comment: **Made some edits.